# String and array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSString *depositOverTotalRwy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [deposit text]];
NSArray *components = [depositOverTotalRwy
                       componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *firstThird = [components objectAtIndex:0];
if ([firstThird isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([firstThird isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([firstThird isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    NSLog(@"ice");
    }
NSString *secThird = [components objectAtIndex:1];
if ([secThird isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([secThird isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([secThird isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    NSLog(@"ice");
}

NSString *thirdThird = [components objectAtIndex:2];

if ([thirdThird isEqualToString: @"1"]) {
    NSLog(@"wet");
}
if ([thirdThird isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    NSLog(@"snow");
}
if ([thirdThird isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    NSLog(@"ice");
}
dep.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ over %@ over %@", firstThird, secThird, thirdThird];
```

Hi guys,
I have a problem. when I set the label (dep.text), I get the number instead of wet, snow or ice. it works in the console (NSlog).
I know it must be some error in the logic but i'm not able to find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example string for `[deposit text]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting  `NSLog(@"snow");` assign `firstThird=@"snow"`

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me as it the objects within components are @"1", @"2" or @"3".

dep.text is reflecting that

for dep.text to resemble what you wish, you need to set the strings, something like -

```
thirdThird = @"wet";

thirdThird = @"snow";

thirdThird = @"ice";
```

inside the conditions of course

}